# Volley StringRequest works but changing it to a JsonObjectRequest results in a com.android.volley.ClientError

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley, asp.net-apicontroller

Please be advised I am just starting out with Kotlin

I have a .NET API with the standard out of the box .NET token based single user account authentication set up.

Assume that the API's are running perfectly as all of this has been verified as working using Postman:

[image: Postman]

The following code is working, and it is a simple StringRequest done in Volley:

```
    val registerRequest = object : StringRequest(Method.POST, TOKEN_URL, Response.Listener { response ->
            Log.i("SmackChatAPI", response)
            var tokenresponse = ""
            token(tokenresponse)
        }, Response.ErrorListener { response ->
            Log.i("SmackChatAPI", "Something went wrong")
            Log.i("SmackChatAPI", response.toString())
            token("")
        }){
            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                var map : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
                //map.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                return map
            }

            override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8"
                //return "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }


            override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                var map : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
                map.put("grant_type","password")
                map.put("username",username)
                map.put("password",password)
                return map
            }
        }
        Log.i("SmackChatAPI", "API called")

        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(registerRequest)
```

Verification that the above code is working:

[image: ADB shell]

But naturally, seeing as this is receiving JSON, I need to be able to Parse it, but the second I convert the function call to a `JsonObjectRequest` I get a

```
com.android.volley.ClientError
```

Here is the malfunctioning code to the same API:

```
        val registerRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, TOKEN_URL, null, Response.Listener { response ->

        var tokenresponse = response.getString("access_token")
        token(tokenresponse)
    }, Response.ErrorListener { response ->
        Log.i("SmackChatAPI", "Something went wrong")
        Log.i("SmackChatAPI", response.toString())
        token("")
    }){
        override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            var map : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
            //map.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            return map
        }

        override fun getBodyContentType(): String {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8"
            //return "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }

        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            var map : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
            map.put("grant_type","password")
            map.put("username",username)
            map.put("password",password)
            return map
        }
    }
    Log.i("SmackChatAPI", "API called")

    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(registerRequest)
```

As you can see all that has changed is the fact that I am now using a `JsonBodyRequest`

[image: JsonBodyRequest Results]

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Body content type would have to be application/json. You have changed the type of request from StringRequest to a JsonRequest, but getBodyContentType remains to be the same. Do not override that method.

Comment: @Dinesh This did not fix my problem unfortunately